# executing piped shell commands in python

Tags: python, shell, subprocess

I need help with python code in executing multiple piped shell commands in python.
I have written the following code but I am getting error. As I am passing the file to the command. Please let me know the correct process on how to execute multiple piped commands in python.

```
EG: cat file|grep -i hostname|grep -i fcid
```

is the shell command I want to execute. Here is my python code. I am getting None when I run the code.I am redirecting the final output to a file.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import subprocess

op = open("text.txt",'w')
file="rtp-gw1"

print("file name is {}".format(file))
#cat file|grep -i "rtp1-VIF"|grep -i "fcid"

#cmd ='cat file|grep -i "rtp1-vif"'
p1  = subprocess.Popen(['cat',file],stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE,shell=True)
p2  = subprocess.Popen(['grep','-i', '"rtp1-vif"',file], stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr= subprocess.PIPE,shell=Ture)
p1.stdout.close()
p3  = subprocess.Popen(['grep', '-i',"fcid"],stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=op,stderr= subprocess.PIPE,shell=Ture)
p2.stdout.close()

result = p3.communicate()[0]

print(result)
```

Comment: `shell=Ture` ? seriously?

Comment: btw why using `cat` ? `grep` can take a file in input you know

Comment: Try closing the files using `p1.communicate(), p2.communicate()` and put them all at the end after getting the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're not getting any result because of this line:

```
['grep','-i', '"rtp1-vif"']
```

this is passing `"rtp1-vif"` *literally* with quotes: no match.

note that the whole piping process is overkill. No need to use `cat` as the first `grep` can take the file as input.

And to go further, it's really easy to perform that task in pure python. Something like:

```
with open("text.txt",'w') as op:
    file="rtp-gw1"

    for line in file:
        line = line.lower()
        if "rtp1-vif" in line and "fcid" in line:
           op.write(line)
```

now your code can run on any platform, without the need to issue external commands. It's probably faster too.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you. That how I started I have a files with more than 100,000+ lines. I have to find lines missing between each file. I am not getting the results I want. That is reason why I wanted to try system commands but will definitely try while loop.